# Expectation of scaled sum of squares of iid random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, expectation

Let $X_1, \dots, X_n$ be iid standard normal random variables. Consider the vector $X = (X_1, \dots, X_n)$ and the vector

$Y = \frac{1}{\|X\|}(X_1, \dots, X_k)$

for $k < n$. What is $\mathbb{E}[\|Y\|^2] = \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{\sum_{i=1}^k X_i^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2} \right]$?

Comment: By symmetry, the result is exactly $$\color{red}{\bf\frac{k}n}.$$

Comment: @Did Thanks, that's exactly the result. Could you please elaborate on your symmetry argument? My reasoning was: The numerator is a Chi-square random variable, with expectation $k$, and the numerator is also a Chi-square random variable with expectation $n$. However,  it is not clear to me how to get $k/n$ from this (cc @ecstasyofgold)

Comment: @Cm7F7Bb Thanks for your suggestion, I will edit the question.

Comment: For every $i\ne j$, the distributions of $(X_i,\|X\|)$ and $(X_j,\|X\|)$ coincide hence $E(X_i^2\|X\|^{-2})=E(X_j^2\|X\|^{-2})$. Summing these from $i=1$ to $n$ yields the expectation of $(X_1^2+\cdots+X_n^2)\|X\|^{-2}=1$ hence $E(X_i^2\|X\|^{-2})=n^{-1}$ for every $i$ and you are done.

Comment: @Did Thanks so much, amazing answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the closed form of this but concentration of measure phenomenon ensures that the expectation will converge to $\frac{k}{n}$ exponentially fast in $k$. So using $k/n$ might be a reasonable approximation.